# How to define a schema for a Spark DataFrame with many columns

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, pandas-groupby

I have a Spark DF `in_df` with over 300 columns with one column of strings and the rest doubles. I need to run a GroupedMap Pandas UDF on it and define the schema of the output before running. In the situation that the output should have the same number of columns but of different types, how do you define that schema? The few examples of Pandas UDF I can find typically just use the schema of `in` as the output schema.

One method I've seen uses `withColumn` and `cast()` on `in_df`. Is that the best practice? What if I want my output to be a completely different shape than `in_df` but too many columns to hand-code? I haven't been able to find a good resource for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uisng `pyspark.sql.types.StructType.fromJson()` you can dynamically construct the schema from the json.

As per your requirement i changed the data type using for "col_e", you can change the DataTypes to one or more columns based on your use case.

```
df = spark.read.csv('test.csv',header=True,inferSchema=True)
fields = []
for f in json.loads(df.schema.json())["fields"]:
    if f["name"] == "col_e":
        fields.append(StructField("col_e", StringType(), True))
    else:
        fields.append(StructField.fromJson(f))

schema = StructType(fields)

@F.pandas_udf(schema, F.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def many_cols_data(pdf):
    pdf['col_e'] = "test"
    return pdf

df.groupBy(
    'col_a'
).apply(
    many_cols_data
).show()
```

input file test.csv

```
col_a,col_b,col_c,col_d,col_e
a,2,3,4,5
b,2,3,4,5
c,2,3,4,5
```

which results

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|col_a|col_b|col_c|col_d|col_e|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    c|    2|    3|    4| test|
|    b|    2|    3|    4| test|
|    a|    2|    3|    4| test|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```